# MYSQL ADD CONSTRAINT ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am getting errors for my add constraints.

I am using MYSQL workbench to create the tables

Message Error from MYSQL workbench:
Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD CONSTRAINT `user_contact_ibfk1` FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES `user_ac' at line 1

Could this just be a version problem I'm having. I'm using 5.2.4.7

Error:

> 22:47:35  ADD CONSTRAINT `user_contact_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user_account` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD CONSTRAINT `user_contact_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user_ac' at line 1    0.000 sec

```
--
-- Table structure for table `user_contact`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_contact` (
  `contact_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `cellnumber` decimal(32,0) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user_profile`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_profile` (
  `profile_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `about_me` text NOT NULL,
  `work_info` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `education_info` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rating` float NOT NULL,
  `user_image` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `friend_array` text NOT NULL,
  `online_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`profile_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;

--
-- Table structure for table `user_account`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_account` (
  `user_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `online_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

--
-- Constraints for table `user_contact`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_contact`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `user_contact_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES    `user_account` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `user_profile`
--

ALTER TABLE `user_profile`
 ADD CONSTRAINT `user_profile_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user_account`     (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: what about user_account table ?

Comment: Sorry, I added it in now.

Comment: It works for me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9650

Comment: could this be an error with my workbench version? I have updated the problem with additional error info.

Comment: I heard workbench is buggy,try running it from phpmyadmin or get http://www.heidisql.com/.

Comment: Unfortunately when presenting this project of mine, the University requires this version of MySQL workbench. :(

Comment: it worked for me too with mysql console of navicat. there is no error about this sql, you should examine your tools I think too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be some internal bug with MYSQL workbench. I used phpmyadmin and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that FOREIGN KEY name might be taken,try changing it.

```
ALTER TABLE `user_contact`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `user_contact_ibfk_stuff` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES    `user_account` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Run this post the result

```
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```

Or directly run this:

```
SET SESSION SQL_MODE='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Comment: @user2901038 Are you sure the queries posted in your question are the same with what you are running?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure about it as I copy/pasted it to make sure. I have other tables in my query that are unrelated to the constraints. Should I add them in?

Comment: No,just make sure the tables are the ones created,you might have preexistent tables with the same name and different columns.Or better yet DROP those 2 tables and run all that stuff again.

Comment: I did drop all the tables and ran the query again. I seem to get the same errors.